Creating a file type of epub in commerce
I want to give customers the option of downloading an epub file or a pdf in Drupal Commerce 2. Drupal 10.
In admin/structure/media types/document/manage fields I added the document file type epub.
When I attempt to upload an epub file to a product variation I am told I cannot as the file extension is not allowed, and all the other file types are listed, but not epub. I have cleared the cache however that particular file type isn’t being picked up. I need to know if I have missed a step.

Sounds to me like your product variation has a different file field on it whose settings will need to be changed in your product variation types interface. If you're using the default file field added to the variation type by the Commerce File module, this is certainly the case.
